# Which theory explains this estimation problem?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a bag with 100 balls, each labeled 1 to 100. Each ball has a color. 10 are green, 20 are red, 20 are yellow, and 50 are blue.
Now someone continuously draws balls from the bag, telling you only the color of the ball, not the label. Each time he draws a ball, he places it back into the bag again, such that he always draws from a bag of 100 balls.

Now after 50 draws, the only thing you know is the number of balls of each color that was drawn.

How do you estimate the average number of times that the same ball was drawn, and which theory would you use? E.g. if 3 balls were drawn, and their numbers were 7, 49 and 7, then the average number of times would be 1.5, as 7 was drawn twice and 49 was drawn once.

The tricky part is that you cannot assume that the person that draws the balls does so at random.

I am looking for a solution for any configuration of the system, the concrete number of balls and colors are just to make the problem easier to understand.

(Sorry for the click-baity title, I honestly have no clue how to properly summarize the problem)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a problem where the selection is neither random nor according to some function, let alone one where it might or might not be. Does it make a difference in practice though? I guess the safest way would be to uniformly distribute probabilities across all possible combinations, rather than calculating the probabilities based on independent draws. But I'm not sure

Comment: Don't worry about the click-bait title.  This is an interesting problem and there are several ways to approach it --- the third one will surprise you!

Comment: I agree that it is strange that the draw is not constraint in any way. You could say that the person drawing the balls can choose to draw based on a distribution he chooses, such that for example there is 70% chance of drawing yellow and 30% chance of drawing blue. Or based on label, like there is 70% chance of drawing label 7 and 30% chance of drawing label 49. I dont know if this is relevant or helps.

Comment: Statistical estimation is impossible, due to the non-randomness: the best you can do is to compute the ranges of possible values.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense.